# Download js libraries according to viewport size

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, webpack

I have hamburger menu that is only relevant for mobiles etc, i.e not to all viewports. Because of that, my *bundle.js* file contains jquery that is not really needed for desktop users of my app. It results in a file size that is larger than needed. I bundle my code with webpack and deploy it as is. Right now, I don't have a separate file for vendors.
The jquery library is imported in *app.js* but I figured out that I can put it in a script tag, check the resolution dynamically and add it to head if meets criteria. Is there any other way to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```html
<script>
    if (screen && screen.width > 900) {
        document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="https://example.com/desktop.js"><\/script>');
    }
</script>

<script>
    if (screen && screen.width < 900) {
        document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="https://example.com/mobile.js"><\/script>');
    }
</script>
```